# How do I get selected value in Jquery Datatable in String format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```js
function unenroll(){
       
        var myTable = $('#enrollment_info').DataTable();
        
        alert("all data is "+allData);
        var selectedrows = myTable.rows('.selected' ).data();
        alert("selected rows"+selectedrows);        
        alert("selected rows length is "+ selectedrows.length)
     }
```

selected rows is showing output but in object format. How can I get it in String format. This table gets populated by a json from Servlet.[image]

Comment: It depends what you need to do with the string? You could turn the object into a JSON string, but will that be of any use to you? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: You need to convert the JSON to the data you need to show in the UI.

Comment: @MacPrawn: I am trying to get the value of first column. A better way to ask is, How will you get values of first of column of selected rows from this datatable ? https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html
At Agalo : yes, I am trying to do that !

Comment: Easiest way to see the structure and content of an object is by using `console.log` instead of `alert` - then look in your browser's developer/javascript console and you should see all the object's properties. That should tell you how to access the first column value.

Comment: thanks @MacPrawn, I am getting all the messages in console :) ,
 myTable.rows('.selected' ).data()[0];  helped me print the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.stringify(); is one direct solution if I'm understanding your question correctly.  You should probably decide exactly what data you need from the table and be a bit more direct about retrieving it.

```js
function unenroll(){
       
        var myTable = $('#enrollment_info').DataTable();
        
        alert("all data is "+allData);
        var selectedrows = JSON.stringify(myTable.rows('.selected' ).data());
        alert("selected rows"+selectedrows);        
        alert("selected rows length is "+ selectedrows.length)
     }
```